# twitter bootstrap icons not displayed as expected, characters instead of

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, character-encoding, icons, font-awesome

Good morning,

I am starting to develop the first html project using twitter-bootstrap and font-awesome framework. I have included both resources in the page without problems. But, when I tried to use the icons as `<i class="icon-wrench intro-icon-large"></i>` it is not showed, instead, a strage symbol is printed:

[image: icons error encoding]

If I inspect the element with firebug, I see the html ok, but in the font-awesome.ss I see this:

```
.icon-wrench:before {
    content: "";
}
```

However, if I open the css file from editor, I see this:

```
.icon-wrench:before{content:"\f0ad"}
```

This behavior confuse me, because all resources are loaded corrently according to the specified path and the icons images are there too.

As additional fact, this happend for every icon, including the native bootstrap icons.

Comment: Did you set the encoding to UTF-8 ?

Comment: I set it in the hmlt header like `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Did you try on Chrome or Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox seems to have some issues with Font-Awesome...

> when using Font Awesome I've found that in Firefox the characters do not render as they should

Here is a "potential" fix : [Font Awesome not working in Firefox (possible fix found)](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/issues/755)

Comment: Thank you! The error was that I did not includ the `font` directory that font-awesome.css was required. Your link was usefull!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CDN. Just include

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in the `<head>` section.